# ArcGIS online live data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, tracking, real-time

Does ArcGIS online have the capability of providing real time (live) tracking of assets?  If I have a staff member with a cell phone can ArcGIS online show me where that person is at any given moment?

I have ArcGIS desktop.  I do not have ArcGIS Server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Esri's solution to these requirements is **[Collector for ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/collector-ios/index.html#//02s20000000m000000)**.

> For your collectors to be tracked while they are working in the field,
>   enable tracking on your map when you author it. ... The following
>   steps enable tracking when working with ArcGIS Online ...

The **[app](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ba47e0bf6cb84a6e9f77e9caf86b88eb)** seems to be free but ...

> **Access and Use Constraints**
>
> ArcGIS Online organizational account or a 30-day trial is required.

Answer (score 0):

Collector for ArcGIS allows in-app tracking, but not "live" tracking. If you want to monitor the location of your field staff in real time then you'll need Workforce for ArcGIS: https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/workforce/overview. This is still a mobile app solution, but is not included in a standard ArcGIS online organisational subscription. You'll need to contact your local esri sales office for more details on licensing.